# Cannot start web app on tomcat from intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij

I 'm new in ubuntu. I'm trying to run a web app on tomcat from intellij but I got this error: **Error running Tomcat  Can't find catalina.jar**

I tried everything I found on forums for this problem, but I can't solve it. Can you help me?

Comment: Please find where that is with `sudo find -type f -iname catalina.jar`

Comment: Good show :) glad  you found it